# Произвольно меняется код php

Tags: php, javascript, html

Ребят, всем привет. Есть сайт, стоит на хостинге reg.ru. В исходниках сайт содержит следующий код:

```
var countvisits = <?php echo $_COOKIE['countvisits'];?>;
```

Но через какое-то время этот код меняется на:

```
var countvisits = {!~comment2~!};
```

Что это может быть? Как это изменить?

Comment: Доступ по фтп? или git? нужно по всем файлам пройтись, которые на серваке... с поисковым запросом на 'countvisits'...это должно указать на места, где нет сомнений, во входящих данных, в куку, Если это не поможет, тогда надо в БД искать аналогично.

Comment: @EvgeniyZaritskiy доступ по фтп
в БД искать нечего, сайт без БД стоит даже, обычный лэндинг
Стоит CMS (если ее можно так назвать) textolite, попробую ее на предмет countvisits проверить